# Проверка пустая ли ячейка или нет

Tags: php, html

Можете подсказать как сделать, чтобы проверялось на наличие текста в ячейке БД.
[image: С текстом и с пустой ячейкой]

```
<div class="label">
 <?php foreach ($books as $data): ?>
  <div class="label__text"><?= $data['label']; ?></div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Подключение к БД:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=localhost","localhost","user");

        $books = [];

        if ($query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Label")){
            echo "<pre>";
                    $books = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo "</pre>";
                } else {
                    print_r($db->errorInfo());
                }
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы когда ячейка пустая, у меня не выводилось ничего. Т.е. без этого оранжевого блока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, **подключение к БД** не вот этот вот ужас, а

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=localhost","localhost","user");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$books = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Label")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Во-вторых, РНР - это язык с нестрогой типизацией и неявным приведением типов. И поэтому "пустая переменная" сама по себе уже эквивалентна булеву значению `false`. Соответственно её можно использовать в условном операторе напрямую:

```
<div class="label">
  <?php foreach ($books as $data): ?>
    <?php if($data['label']): ?>
      <div class="label__text"><?= htmlspecialchars($data['label']) ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Если вы хотите писать более строгий код и не полагаться на неявное приведение типов, можете использовать явное сравнение, `if($data['label'] === '')` или `if($data['label'] === null)`, в зависимости от того, какое именно "пустое значение" хранится в БД.

При этом использовать как `empty()`, так и `isset()` для заведомо существующей переменной совершенно бессмысленно.

Обратите внимание, я добавил к выводу htmlspecialchars. Эта функция в обязательном порядке должна применяться к любому выводу переменных в контексте HTML.